# Sorting XML by attribute Name

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-2.0

How can I rearrange the XML based on Property Name value and then save it in following order- Hostname, DNSDomain, Environment,HWSystemType,SystemType,HWSystemModel

Thank you for helping.

```
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="Hostname">myServer</Property>
    <Property Name="SystemType">Physical</Property>
    <Property Name="HWSystemModel">Windows Server</Property>
    <Property Name="HWSystemType">Unitary HW-System</Property>
    <Property Name="DNSDomain">Domain.net</Property>
    <Property Name="Environment">Testing</Property>
 </Object>
</Objects>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want to do?  Generally, the goal of XML is to focus purely on data, while other tools operate on the XML for purpose of presentation.  Maybe you could say a little more about the "big picture" of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I also noticed that your closing tags (`<Object>` and `<Objects>`) are not properly formatted.  Should be:  `</Object>` and `</Objects>`

Comment: I noticed you didn't include `HWSystemModel` in your specified order.

Comment: Purpose is to properly arrange the XML in the order specified so that the XSL can just render the columns as is. We don't have skills and time to work on XSL, which is bit difficult for us. So we want to keep the xml simple, thank you for helping on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sorting the XML by `@Name` (but note the alphabetic order is different to what you listed), try

```
Select-Xml -Path Your.xml -XPath //Property | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - here you go.  Simply run this script (sortxml.ps1) and re-direct the output to the file of your choice, e.g. `sortxml.ps1 > sorted_xml_file.xml`

NOTE:  requires the [Powershell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) module for `Format-Xml`.

sortedxml.ps1:

```
# replace 'old.xml' with the path to your unsorted xmlfile
[xml]$xml = gc old.xml
[xml]$xmlnew = gc old.xml

$names = @('Hostname', 'DNSDomain', 'Environment', 'HWSystemType', 'SystemType', 'HWSystemModel' )

$nodes = $xmlnew.Objects.Object.Property
foreach($i in 0..($names.length - 1)) {
    foreach($j in $xml.Objects.Object.Property) {
        if($j.Name -eq $names[$i]) {
            $nodes[$i].Name = $j.Name
            $nodes[$i]."#text" = $j."#text"
            break
        }
    }
}

Format-Xml -inputobject $xmlnew
```